# работа с двумя вкладками puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

У меня есть открыты 2 вкладки сайта. При изменении DOM на первом мне нужно на втором кликнуть на элемент и собрать информацию з DOM. А потом снова ждать эвента на первом и при срабатывании что-то делать на втором и так по кругу. Как это мне реализовать, возможно есть готовая стуктура, и реально ли вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, вы можете использовать [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction).

Для первой вкладки через [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) регистрируете обработчик изменений ([`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)) и из него вызываете exposed function, которая уже обрабатывает вторую вкладку.